# View [errors.404] not found

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am opening a page which is not present in my application and in order to get rid of 404 error, I wrote below code.

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
            case '404':
                return \Response::view('errors.404');
        }
    }
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Directory structure is like below and you could see there is 404 Blade inside errors directory

[My Directory Structure here. Please click it to view the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhRVM.png)

When I run the above code, it shows below error.

> View [errors.404] not found

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix typo in the filename. **Blade** is misspelled.

You named your file: 404.bade.php instead of 404.**blade**.php

[image]

Comment: No change in code is required. Just rename the file.

Comment: Thank You very much, Upvoted for the very useful help.